# Peticion de una url adicional

Tags: ajax

Estimados tengo este código consumiendo esta api en json, necesito mostrar en el div o class homeworld, el nombre del planeta, me comentan que tengo que hacer una petición adicional entrando en la ruta del servicio figura el item homeworld el cual tiene una url con el planeta correspondiente pero como puedo hacer para mostrar el nombre lo que he podido es mostrar el texto de la url pero no el nombre su ayuda por favor, y no he podido estructurar como hacerlo, les dejo el código que tengo. gracias.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('https://swapi.co/api/people/', function(datos) {
        var output = '<article class="row">';
        $.each(datos.results, function(i, item) {
            output += '<div class="col">';
            output += '<div class="inner">';
            output += '<div class="name">' + item.name + '</div>';
            output += '<div class="height"><strong>Altura :</strong> ' + item.height + '</div>';
            output += '<div class="hair_color"><strong>Color de Cabello :</strong> ' + item.hair_color + '</div>';
            output += '<div class="birth_year"><strong>Cumpleaños :</strong> ' + item.birth_year + '</div>';
            output += '<div class="homeworld">' + item.homeworld + '</div>';
            output += '</div>';
            output += '</div>';
        });

        output += '</article>';
        $('.container').html(output);

    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
        <h2>Personajes Star Wars</h2>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row"><span>Cargando...</span></div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí tienes el código, he puesto comentarios para que lo entiendas mejor, básicamente he recuperado las url dónde obtengo los planetas y luego las he tratado para recuperar el nombre y añadir-lo al html.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var urlsPlanetas = [];//contendra todas las url de los planetas que debemos recuperar
    $.getJSON('https://swapi.co/api/people/', function(datos) {
        var output = '<article class="row">';
        $.each(datos.results, function(i, item) {
            output += '<div class="col">';
            output += '<div class="inner">';
            output += '<div class="name">' + item.name + '</div>';
            output += '<div class="height"><strong>Altura :</strong> ' + item.height + '</div>';
            output += '<div class="hair_color"><strong>Color de Cabello :</strong> ' + item.hair_color + '</div>';
            output += '<div class="birth_year"><strong>Cumpleaños :</strong> ' + item.birth_year + '</div>';
            output += '<div class="homeworld"></div>';
            output += '</div>';
            output += '</div>';
            
           urlsPlanetas.push(item.homeworld);


            
        });
        output += '</article>';
        //tratamos url planetas y lo añadimos a output, esto se ejecuta cuando ya tenemos el html
        urlsPlanetas.forEach(function(item,index){
          $.getJSON(item,null,function(datos){
              var prova = datos.results;
              $.each(datos, function(key, val) {
                if(key.indexOf('name')!=-1){//cuando encuentre el nombre lo añadimos a nuestro html
                  $($(".homeworld")[index]).replaceWith("<div/><strong>Planeta :</strong> "+val);
                }
              });
          });
        });
        $('.container').html(output);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
        <h2>Personajes Star Wars</h2>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row"><span>Cargando...</span></div>
        </div>
    </section>
```